# Submit form with action attribute hidden

Tags: php, javascript, forms

People

I want to know how to submit form without action attribute shown.
Like this

```
<form action="someact.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Some suggest to use `$_PHP['SELF']`, but I want my form to be processed using another php file like separating UI part and process part so that anyone can't see my process file ?

I want like this

```
<form method="post">
...
</form>
```

But it processed to the file I want.

Help please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I don't quite understand why you would want this. The whole point of the `action` attribute is to tell the browser where to send the request, and "hiding" it achieves nothing - any half-way competent hacker (or even less than half-way) can still find the information you are hiding, no matter what you do.

Having said that, you could do something like this:

```
<form id="hidden_action_form" method="post">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('hidden_action_form').action = 'someact.php';
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why on earth would you need a "hidden" process file? That's impossible: the browser has to know where the request should be sent.

If you explain the problem you're having in the first place, and not the problem that arose from your solition to that problem, other people might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I get the impression that you mix up two things. The PHP-file is only on your server and will not be sent over to the browser. The server (normally apache httpd) processes the file and generates HTML code from it. This code is then sent over to the browser.

When you have a form you MUST have an action associated because as CodeCaster pointed out: The browser needs to know where to send the data. It's like a hyper link without setting the href-Attribute. Nothing can ever happen because the browser does not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to hide that without javascript. Even javascript won't hide it, but can post the data to another file while the user gets directed to the (public) file defined in the action of the form.

You can use an ajax [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call to POST data to another file. See the link provided to do this with jQuery and make sure that ajax sends the post first and then redirects/loads the user-content.

Notice though that if a client has javascript disabled, the whole POST will **not** be executed. Also if someone takes a look into your js, one can see the *hidden* filename there too, unless you password-protect the js file.

Comment: This is as close as you're going to get to an answer for this question +1

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. A form must always have an action attribute.
Noone can see the contents of the file that is going to process the form data (if this is your problem).

Comment: I was wondering the same thing about mine - some people just think that downvoting without explanation is a fun pass-time... +1 to counter.

Comment: What can you say...Anyway, thanks for the upvote, wish i could do the same for you.