# Django Form post action

Tags: django, forms

So I can't figure it out how to make form submit action link to external website be invisible in inspect element. For example I got my html form something like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='some link to external website'> <div>{{ form }}</div>
```

Is it possible to make it hidden or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do this, the browser has to know where to send requests. Although, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888230/13273250) may help you.